# Web API parameter accept any parameter after valid one

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have API that have one parameter string UserId a but while testing it accept any parameter after the parameter i have defined like this

http://localhost:xxxx/api/get?UserId=43141688 its shows the result I wanted and i have one parameter that is UserId but if I do like this

"http://localhost:xxxx/api/get?UserId=43141688&xyzpqr  and also gets the same result on the basis of UserId
and &xyzpqr is not valid

so how to do parameter binding basis of my parameter no additional (? and & )include only UserId?

What I have tried:

I already tried attribute based routing and action-based routing

Comment: "43141688&xyzpqr" will be read as whole, try to make it "?UserId=43141688&xyzpqr=test"

Comment: @jomsk1e Stills gets the same result ..  why don't its showing the error

Comment: I think Web API is just trying its' best to pick a route which at least matches some of the URI (in this case `UserId`). I guess it comes down to if this is an actual issue for you or not

Comment: Have you tried this with using the Request body in lieu of Query String? (I know that doesn't answer the question, just asking out of curiosity)

Comment: @MarkC. I use custom parameter binding for this solution

Comment: [article](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-and-greedy-query-string-parameter-binding) here this article will help @MarkC.

Comment: That looks to be exactly what you need. Did you implement that?

Comment: yes, I did implement this problem get solved